# How can I insert a variable into this json object?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am creating a Rails application that will talk to TeamSnap's API through this post:

```
def create_team
  RestClient.post("https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams", '{"team": {"team_name": 
  "Braves", "sport_id": 1, "timezone": "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "country": 
  "United States", "zipcode": 80302}}',content_type: :json,
   x_teamsnap_token: '000-000-000-000')
end
```

The RestClient.post works fine, but as you can see, all the information is hard-coded.  I want to be able to use variables inside this post, so I can grab them from my application and then send them through this post and TeamSnap's API where it will create a new team on TeamSnap with this information.

In other words, I will have a form, for instance, in my application where you can enter a new team name.  I want to pass this value into this object instead of having to hard code it (i.e. "Braves").  The object will not work unless you use quotes.  I tried creating a variable @team_name and replacing "Braves" with it, but it won't work.  **Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

You can use strong parameters to get the data that was posted by the form:

```
def team_params
  params.require(:team).permit(:team_name)
end
```

And then in `create_team` you can convert this hash to a json string:

```
def create_team
  RestClient.post("https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams", team_params.to_json, content_type: :json, x_teamsnap_token: '000-000-000-000')
end
```

**Edit:** To test this code, you can hardcode the value of `:team_name` like this:

```
def create_team
  team_params = {team: {team_name: 'Gophers'}}

  RestClient.post("https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams", team_params.to_json, content_type: :json, x_teamsnap_token: '000-000-000-000')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am fairly new - can you tell me how to hard code :team_name to test this out? i.e., how can I set :team_name to "Gophers" or whatever so I can test this? Thanks

Comment: I tried the updated code and got this error: param is missing or the value is empty: team

Comment: @david This code assumes that a form sent the values, so it's not really possible to use it without a real request. Updated the example which uses a simple hash.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Will try it again.  Thank you for continuing to help.

Answer (score 1):

RestClient can accept hash as params. Yon don't have to convert it to json in your code.

```
RestClient.post 'https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams', {"team" => {"team_name" => params[:team_name], ...}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am fairly new - can you tell me how to hard code :team_name to test this out? i.e., how can I set :team_name to "Gophers" or whatever so I can test this?  Thanks

Comment: @david if you are using rails, then params is represented the value submit by the user, you can just set params[:team_name] = "Gophers" inside your action code inside the controller. You can also test it with a plain ruby script, and just set the team_name to a variable.

Comment: i'm getting a 403 error.  here's what i have: def team_params
    params.permit(:team_name)
  end    def create_team
    params[:team_name] = "Gophers"
    RestClient.post('https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams', {"team" => {"team_name" => params[:team_name], "sport_id" => 1, 
    "timezone" => "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "country" => "United States", "zipcode" => 80302}, content_type: :json, 
      x_teamsnap_token: '000-000-000'}) end

Answer (score 1):

You can always do simple string insertion via Ruby:

```
def create_team(team_name, sport_id, zip_code)
  RestClient.post("https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams", "{\"team\": {\"team_name\": 
  \"#{team_name}\", \"sport_id\": #{sport_id}, \"timezone\": \"Mountain Time (US & Canada)\", \"country\": 
  \"United States\", \"zipcode\": #{zip_code}}}',content_type: :json,
  x_teamsnap_token: '000-000-000-000')
end
```

That's `#{}` syntax around a variable name into a String. I should mention that this only works in double-quotes, not single quotes. So you'll need to change up the syntax and escape the other double quotes for this to work, as in the example above.

There are definitely more elegant ways to handle this, but that'll get you to the next step.